# WebAPI: No action was found on the controller 'MobileApp' that matches the name 'services'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have configured the following

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And have the following web api

```
public class MobileAppController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("api/mobileapp/services")]
    public dynamic services()
    {
        return new { Abc = 123 };
    }   
}
```

I get the error when calling http://localhost:123/api/mobileapp/services

No action was found on the controller 'MobileApp' that matches the name 'services'

Comment: can you share the WebApiConfig?

Comment: Do you have `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in your `WebApiConfig.cs` ?

Comment: @Igor yes if you didn't add `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` this line to your api config the method routes are not works.

Comment: Yes, I have config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

Comment: @Igor That would only matter if there wasn't a route mapping in place.

Comment: Is the code in your startup actually being called? Does it execute your route config?

Comment: @Craig we are left guessing because the question in its current state is incomplete. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem and help identify a possible solution. By all accounts what you have there should work, so that means that there is something you are not showing that is causing the problem.

Comment: have you followed all steps here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: i copied Your code and it works fine... You have problem somewhere else

Answer (score -4):

Change the return value of the action to IActionResult

Comment: it's not make sense. he can return dynamic object

Comment: @arslanaybars True, but an API should never return `dynamic`

Comment: that has nothing to do with the fact that the "no action was found" exception throws. dynamic might not be the best solution here but that's another story

Comment: @DavidG ofc returning dynamic is not maybe good practices. but the question"s problems looks something different.